# How do I integrate this finite integral?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

How to do this integration?

$$
\int\limits^{1/2T}_{-1/2T} \cos (2 \pi fT) \left| \frac {j2 \pi fT (1+e^{-j2 \pi fT})^4}{(1-e^{-j2 \pi fT})} \right|^2 df
$$
After simplification as much as I can I get this:
$$
= \int\limits^{1/2T}_{-1/2T} \frac{2^8 (\pi fT)^2 \cos (2 \pi fT)  \cos^8 (\pi fT)}{ \sin^2 (\pi fT)} df$$

$$= \int\limits^{1/2T}_{-1/2T} \frac {2^9 (\pi fT)^2 \cos^{10} (\pi fT)}{\sin^2(\pi fT)} df - \int\limits^{1/2T}_{-1/2T} \frac {2^8 (\pi fT)^2 \cos^8 (\pi fT)}{\sin^2(\pi fT)} df$$

But I don't know how to proceed?

Comment: I tried to edit some things but other things are beyond my comprehension...Besides this, what have you tried? Where is your own work and effort in this?

Comment: My work lies in translating the problem I'm trying to solve into this integration. I have tried reduction formulas but they did not get me anywhere. Maybe I was wrong to ask what I didn't know how to do! I'm not sure what the negative marks are for?

Comment: Those downvotes try to convey to you that some people doesn't like questions that look like requesting people to do **all** the work. I usually don't downvote, but I also dislike questions that don't show some serious effort, no matter how little of it is there.

Comment: Right. Let me also add that when you don't "see" effort/s, it does not necessarily mean that there isn't any!

Comment: Perhaps @Elnaz...but most of us haven't been blessed with guessing skills, so...

Comment: Then you don't judge based on what you don't know...

Comment: Oh, dear: I didn't, Elnaz. I did judge on what I saw, and I saw no self effort on your side. The ones that did downvote your post also judged *and acted*. This is the way this site works. Don't like it? Well, we all are free to surf the web as we want...

Comment: What you see is not all that there exist. I just put the part of my problem which I did not know how to solve, i.e. the "all math" part. This surely doesn't mean that I want others to do all the work ... If you don't know how to help as you said yourself "we all are free to surf the web...".

Comment: before you continue arguing perhaps you should read the general directions for people posting questions in this site. Have you done this?

Comment: More to the point:  What is the $|$ in the first integrand, and why can't you use `\frac{numer}{denom}` to make the formulas more readable?

Comment: @SammyBlack |.| stands for the magnitude. And, thanks, I edited the post.

Answer (score 1):

One way to evaluate each of these integrals is to convert $\cos^{2k}(\pi f T)$ to $(1-\sin^2(\pi f T))^2$, expand, simplify, and integrate.